# Sitecore form section does not show "form-section" and "row" div when "Section" field is added on the Form

Tags: sitecore-forms

We are using sitecore forms with Sitecore 9.3 and facing the below issue on one of the lower environments.

When we add "Section", the below div structure generates

```
<div class="form-section">
 <div class="row">
  <div data-sc-field-key="SITECOREID">
    All ELEMENTS
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Below is a screenshot from the content editor for the form
[image]

We have packaged the form to another environment with the same setup, but the HTML generates as below

```
<div data-sc-field-key="SITECOREID">
    All ELEMENTS
</div>
```

Below is a screenshot from the content editor for the form
[image]
"form-section" and "row" Divs are missing.
Could you help in identifying how the  structures are generated for the Forms ?

Comment: The OOTB structure of the section contains `<div data-sc-field-key="@Model.ConditionSettings.FieldKey" class="@Model.CssClass">`. Can you check if something is modified in the `section.cshtml` on the higher environment?

Comment: section.cshtml is exact same as you mentioned in both the environments

Comment: The 2 divs are not rendered at all on the other environment. the example in my question is the exact html structure being generated for the section.

Comment: @MarekMusielak, I could not see these classes anywhere in option on "section" on the form in content editor or form editor and unable to identify how these 2 wrapper divs are generated in one environment.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot from Content Editor with forms from both environments?

Comment: Hello @MarekMusielak,  Did you mean from FormBuilder ? and do you need any specific field options that I could highlight ?

Comment: No, I mean Content Editor. Every form is in fact an item in Sitecore tree. Every form element, like form page, form section, form field are also Sitecore items. When you open form in form builder, the url is like `/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Pages/FormDesigner?sc_formmode=edit&formId=%7B043D8F67-4413-41A9-A657-4D72156A9595%7D` Copy ID between `%7B` and `%7D` and find it in Content  Editor on both environments. Expand all nodes under them and add screenshots to your question

Comment: The forms are exact same on both the environments as I have packaged out from 1 to another. I have attached the images in the question for your reference. Let me know, if you could provide any more information. Thanks for taking your time out for this.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to point towards some customisation that was applied in one environment but not the other.

I just did a scan of a vanilla 93 installation and I couldnt find any reference to "form-section".

That being the case, please check this path in the both environments: `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Field Types/Structure/Section` and confirm that the `View Path` field is set to **FieldTemplates/Section**.

If both are the same, please then do a full scan of the lower environment to find where exactly the HTML `<div class="form-section">` is coming from, as I dont believe this to be OTB.

Comment: Hello Dean, I have verified the View path of "/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Field Types/Structure/Section" on both the environment, Its set to "FieldTemplates/Section". I could not find the "form-section" class in any files under "Views\FormBuilder". Let me know, if there is a way to change the html structure of the OTB Form elements.